# FMOD_System_Init Crash

Tags: c++, fmod

I'm trying to use the FMOD audio API in my game but the app starts and then closes. I tried to debug it and the program crashes at the FMOD_System_Init function.

```
void AudioSystem::Init() {
    FMOD_System_Create(&sys); // FMOD_SYSTEM* sys;
    FMOD_System_Init(sys, 32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0); // Crash
}
```

Called here:

```
int Game::MainLoop(int fpscap) {
    // ...
    // Expose classes to the scripting engine
    // FPS calculations

    m_audiosys->Init(); // AudioSystem* m_audiosys;

    // Initialize Input, Window, Main Game, etc...
    // Game Loop...

    // ...
}
```

This is the fmod.log file:

```
FMOD: SystemI::init                  : FMOD Ex Version: 00044458
FMOD: SystemI::init                  : maxchannels = 16, flags = 00000000,     extradriverdata = 00000000
FMOD: SystemI::close                 : 
FMOD: SystemI::close                 : Stop all sounds
FMOD: SystemI::close                 : Remove miscllaneous DSP stuff.
FMOD: SystemI::close                 : done.

FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Enumerating...
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Initialise COM library.
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Found Driver: "SONY TV (Áudio do     vídeo Intel(R))".
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Found Driver: "Alto-falantes     (Dispositivo de High Definition Audio)".
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Found Driver: "Alto-falantes (XSplit      Stream  Audio  Renderer)".
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Found Driver: "Microfone (Dispositivo     de High Definition Audio)".
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::enumerate        : Done.
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::initEx           : Initialising...
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::initEx           : Done.
FMOD: SystemI::init                  : Set up software engine
FMOD: Thread::initThread             : Initializing FMOD (WASAPI) feeder      thread.  priority 0
FMOD: Thread::initThread             : - Stacksize 0.  Stack pointer     00000000 : usesemaphore = 0 : sleeptime = 0
FMOD: Thread::callback               : * FMOD (WASAPI) feeder thread started
FMOD: Thread::initThread             : done.
FMOD: OutputWASAPI::feederUpdate     : WASAPI feeder thread set to 'Audio'     characteristic
FMOD: Thread::initThread             : Initializing FMOD mixer thread.      priority 2
FMOD: Thread::initThread             : - Stacksize 49152.  Stack pointer     00000000 : usesemaphore = 1 : sleeptime = 0
```

It works if I run step-by-step. It goes on a bunch of machine code and if I keep jumping the program starts and everything works just fine.

I'm not trying to play any sound yet, just FMOD initialization for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages! Do not add C tag for C++ questions

Comment: Check for race-conditions.

Comment: I'm using the C API of FMOD (The C++ one doesn't work with MinGW). That's why I put C there. Also I don't see any differences apart from the OOP

Comment: Ok, It might be a race-condition, but what do I do? It's a closed-source library :/